# Sum of rows as the last record from Postgresql query result

Tags: sql, postgresql

My Table column is like this, I want the sum of all records in the last row without using UNION

```
no_of_books
1
3
3
3
5
```

Expected result would be

```
no_of_books
    1
    3
    3
    3
    5
   15
```

I have tried like this, but looking for better fuctions in PostgreSQL like Oracle

```
select aa.no_of_books sum_prod  from (SELECT prodcount
FROM "table1") aa
union all
select sum(bb.sum_prod) from (
select aa.no_of_books sum_prod  from (SELECT prodcount
FROM "table1") aa ) bb
```

OR

```
select no_of_books
from table t 
union all
select sum(no_of_books)
from table t ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rollup` with subquery :

```
select coalesce(no_of_books, (select sum(no_of_books) from table t))
from table t
group by rollup(no_of_books);
```

However, this would be done with `sum()` directly :

```
select sum(no_of_books)
from table t
group by rollup(no_of_books);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `rollup` :

```
select sum(no_of_books)
  from books t
 group by rollup(no_of_books)
```

or `cube`

```
select sum(no_of_books)
  from books t
 group by cube(no_of_books);
```

[(`SQL Fiddle Demo`)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c50c5/2)